# Fetch DNS record information java

Tags: java, dns, ip, mx-record

Is there a library in *java* to fetch accurate **DNS** information from underlying server?

I am interested not only in **IP** to **DNS** mapping, but also in other records: *A, AAAA, MX, NS, SOA, RRSIG e t.c.*.

Answer (score 5):

If your code runs on the Oracle VM, you can use the DNS provider for JNDI, e.g.:

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "dns:");

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes atts = ctx.getAttributes("stackexchange.com", new String[] {"MX"});
NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> e = atts.getAll();
while(e.hasMore()) {
    System.out.println(e.next().get());
}
```

Comment: there is an ipv6 related issue with this solution

Comment: @builtofire: Care to explain?

Comment: @builtofire: To be more precise, the MX records which are queried here contains a priority and a host name and are in no way related to IPv4 or IPv6 addresses. What kind of IPv6 issue are you talking about?

Comment: you get an exception like this one if the ipv6 is enabled on the machine :
`Exception:
Failed to resolve Mail Exchanger for host : gmail.com
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4f8:0:a111::add:9898"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
 at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.<init>(DnsClient.java:122) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
 at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.<init>(Resolver.java:61) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
 at `

Comment: Looks as a problem with the DNS configuration of your system and not a problem with my code or the DNS implementation in the Java API. 4f8:0:a111::add:9898 is *not* a valid IPv6 address. If you have configured that as your DNS server and some software don't cope with that, it's a problem with your DNS configuration.

Comment: well this is related to this : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6991580 , and for you information if it is an invalid ipv6 address then the implementation should notify this with a proper exception, NumberFormatException sound like something went wrong in the implementation. what i was trying to say here is : it is better to use a 3rd party library to be safe in the deployment phase, then to stick to sun's classes.  This looks like a valid address to me : 4f8:0:a111::add:9898 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address). i see u have a lot of rating here but i dont understand why u bein

Comment: Ok, perhaps the bug is only relevant for Linux. I have a Windows computer here with an IPv6 name server and everything works as expected. The address is invalid, because IPv6 addresses starting with 0 in the first four bits are IPv4 addresses mapped into the IPv6 name space and must contain a globally unique IPv4 address in the last four octets. Your address maps to 10.221.152.152, which is not a globally unique addrress, but an IPv4 address reserved for private networks.

Comment: Would this work on OpenJDK 11?

Answer (score 2):

better to use the dnsjava lib :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and an example looks like this :

```
Record[] rs = new Lookup("maildomain.com", Type.MX).run();
```

Comment: how use it in android